# Set input in 2 Entry using button in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made two entry widgets: `account_number_entry` and `pin_number_entry` and button 0-9

```
# Account number entry here
account_number_entry = tk.Entry(f, textvariable=account_number_var, width=12, font=('Helvetica 15'), bd=10)

account_number_entry.grid(row=45, column=1)
# Account pin entry here
account_pin_entry = tk.Entry(f, text='PIN Number', textvariable=pin_number_var, show=('*'), width=8,
                             font=('Helvetica 15'), bd=10)
account_pin_entry.grid(row=45, column=2)
```

and I have created button as

```
b1 = tk.Button(f, text='1', font=('Helvetica 12 '), width=15, height=6,command=lambda: set_text("1"))
b1.grid(row=50, column=0)
```

set_text function is like this

```
def set_text(text):
    account_number_entry.insert(tk.END, text)
    return
```

but I can't add data pin Entry. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In `account_number_entry` you have set `textvariable=account_number_var`, this means you can simplify the callback as follows:

```
def set_text(text):
    account_number_var.set(text)
```

But in case you still prefer to use `account_number_entry`  then you should code the function like this:

```
def set_text(text):
    account_number_entry.delete(0,END)
    account_number_entry.insert(0, text)
```

I [called](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) `delete` because I suppose you want to write new text there.
Note also it is useless to write the `return` statement in this situation.